# Swift Package Manager SecureTransport error: connection closed via error (-1)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Trying to add the `KeychainAccess` package, with Xcode 12.4(12D4e).

Copy-paste the git / http URL of the GitHub repo, click next

--- Xcode: authentication --->

set package version, click next

--- Xcode: Starting package resolution --->

Then Xcode failed to resolve the package, with an error:

`SecureTransport error: connection closed via error (-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's kinda a network issue: Xcode does not comply with my proxy settings.

Using Proxifier solved my problem. Or you can move the proxy onto your router / switch.